# Word 2010 VBA Macro: loop to end of document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have recorded a simple macro to find the word "Quantity", go to the end of that line and insert a carriage return. I need to repeat it to the end of the document and quit, or else I'll have an infinite loop.

The code:

```
     Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
     With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Quantity:"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.TypeParagraph
```

Comment: And what is the issue you are having? As with all programming, please be specific.

Comment: The word "quantity" repeats an unspecified number of times in the document, and I don't know how to repeat the macro until the end of the document and stop.

Answer (score 2):

Change you code to this, note the use of wdFindStop.

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
     With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Quantity:"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

do while Selection.Find.Execute = true
   Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.TypeParagraph  
loop
```

If you have the type of documents this can fail on you can use the Selection.Start by 
replacing the loop like this:

```
Dim lastPos As Long
lastPos = -1
Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True
    If lastPos > Selection.Start Then Exit Do
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.TypeParagraph
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll` after your End with