# How to change format of current paragraph without using Selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the code below without using `Selection`.

```
Sub Format paragraph()

Dim wdDoc As Document

    With wdDoc.Range.Find 
       .Font.Size = 12
       .Text = "?" 
       .Execute 
    End With
End Sub
```

When the character with font size = 12 is found, how can I change the format of the current paragraph? for example:

```
wdDoc.Paragraph(current).Font.Size = 14

wdDoc.Paragraph(current).Font.Color = wdBlue
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to work with a specific `Range` object, which can be used to access its "parent" paragraph. When `Find.Execute` is successful, the `Range` being searched contains the found item (same as the selection jumps to the found item).  For example:

```
Sub Format paragraph()
  Dim rng as Range, para as Paragraph
  Dim wdDoc As Document

  Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument. 'Missing in code in question...
  Set rng = wdDoc.Content 'Content returns the Range
    With rng.Find 
       .Font.Size = 12
       .Text = "?" 
       If .Execute = True Then
         Set para = rng.Paragraphs(1)
         para.Font.Size = 14
         para.Font.Color = wdBlue
       End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Cindy_Meister Hi Cindy. Thanks for your answer. That seems to be what I need. There are several paragraphs, some with font size 12 and others with other fonts. So, how to include your `With rng.find` block in a `while` loop? Or should I count first the paragraphs that match the style I want and then do a `for loop` to apply the same changes to the other paragraphs?

Comment: @GerCas a loop is the usual way. There are lots of examples for using that with `Find` here and elsewhere. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/52596708/3077495 Rather than applying manual formatting you might consider applying a *paragraph STYLE* that defines the required formatting. That's just one step and, if the formatting needs to change again at a later point, simply changing the style definition is one-step in the UI - no macro required.

Comment: @Cindy_Meister Hi Cindy. Thanks fot you suggestions and link shared.